# How can I get my data off the hard drive that won't power on?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Westell 160gb external that will no longer power on, how can I get my data off the hard drive?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Check the power supply, if it uses an external one.  That *may* be the issue.
If it seems fine, or there's no external one, you *may* be able to recover your data, but it is likely to require dismantling the unit, and there is no guarantee of success.

Recovery will only be practical if there is a SATA or IDE hard drive inside the unit, that can be removed and connected directly to a computer.  This will allow access to the data *if and only if the drive itself is undamaged*.  Otherwise, the only ways to access the data are highly involved and likely to be quite expensive.